# Raspberry Pi - Wireless to Ethernet Internet Forward

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have no idea if this is even possible and I have searched but cannot find much on this.
Basically I have A Raspberry PI 3, connected via wireless.  Is it possible to connect the Ethernet to say - a CCTV DVR and forward the internet onto this?

The DVR does not have wireless.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, It's possible. What you're looking for is turning the Raspberry Pi 3 into an **Access Point**. Google Search that. And you should of asked the question here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Its on topic here.